# Asp.netcore app in docker debian

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, microservices

I have problem to run my container in docker, my docker is host on a server linux debian
this is my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY DockerWebPage/DockerWebPage.csproj DockerWebPage/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/DockerWebPage
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerWebPage.dll"]
```

and this is my console output:

```
root@vps564358:~# docker build -t  dockerwebpage:dev /home/Container
Sending build context to Docker daemon    352MB
Step 1/18 : too much code for send all console build 
b1dd0b04c119: Pull complete
91ea08ab0cc9: Pull complete
7f2893df5d93: Pull complete
6ca202fa6c2e: Pull complete
31b4abd59648: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1e4043c2484157e029d6b09a3149ebd01c5122f6b62f0a1b6c6f54b90500ea4b
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
 ---> e4e43a027c0b
Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> bf0be7525f14
Removing intermediate container 9ff4196e50dc
Step 7/18 : COPY *.sln ./
No source files were specified
root@vps564358:~# docker run -d -p 5000:5000 dockerwebpage:dev
9fe41e5b2237364e141ed575c02afc02755b8a751ba65e57a395a8b633b5d022
```

so i think after that my web app could work, but when i try to connect to my site i have a error :"Connetion denied from "

Comment: Try to post your question here.  https://serverfault.com/

Comment: You are getting an error during the image build process.
No source files were specified
Seems that you are running the docker build in a location where there is no *.sln file